# Convert a string to datetime in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am using PowerShell to try and convert a string to a datetime. It should be easy, right?

I am getting the string from a CSV import, and it comes in the format of `Jul-16`. I have tried multiple ways of getting it into the format I want which is `yyyy-MM-dd` and I am currently at the following.

```
$invoice = $object.'Invoice Month'
$invoice = "01-" + $invoice
$invoice = [datetime]::parseexact($invoice, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
```

But I get the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The string *comes* in the format `Jul-16`, so why are you parsing it with `yyyy-MM-dd` rather than `MMM-dd`? You're confusing this with *formatting* the string as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

ParseExact is told the format of the date it is expected to parse, not the format you wish to get out.

```
$invoice = '01-Jul-16'
[datetime]::parseexact($invoice, 'dd-MMM-yy', $null)
```

If you then wish to output a date string:

```
[datetime]::parseexact($invoice, 'dd-MMM-yy', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: If the input is in a known standard format, you can use Parse instead of ParseExact without needing to provide the format.

Answer (score 55):

You can simply cast strings to DateTime:

```
[DateTime]"2020-7-16"
```

or

```
[DateTime]"Jul-16"
```

or

```
$myDate = [DateTime]"Jul-16";
```

And you can format the resulting DateTime variable by doing something like this:

```
'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f [DateTime]'Jul-16'
```

or

```
([DateTime]"Jul-16").ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

or

```
$myDate = [DateTime]"Jul-16";
'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $myDate
```

Comment: This should be the answer, most declarative solution that will meet most users needs.

Comment: This is good to a point.  It won't work for more complex strings eg '26/Apr/2023:16:34:14'.  Need to use ParseExact in these cases.

Answer (score 14):

You need to specify the format *it already has*, in order to parse it:

```
$InvoiceDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($invoice, "dd-MMM-yy", $null)
```

Now you can output it in the format you need:

```
$InvoiceDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

or

```
'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $InvoiceDate
```

Answer (score 5):

Chris Dents' answer has already covered the OPs' question but seeing as this was the top search on google for `PowerShell format string as date` I thought I'd give a different string example.

---

If like me, you get the time string like this `20190720170000.000000+000`

An important thing to note is you need to use `ToUniversalTime()` when using `[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]` otherwise you get offset times against your input.

### PS Code

```
cls
Write-Host "This example is for the 24hr clock with HH"
Write-Host "ToUniversalTime() must be used when using [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]"
$my_date_24hr_time   = "20190720170000.000000+000"
$date_format         = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($my_date_24hr_time).ToUniversalTime();
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($my_date_24hr_time).ToUniversalTime().ToSTring($date_format)
[datetime]::ParseExact($my_date_24hr_time,"yyyyMMddHHmmss.000000+000",$null).ToSTring($date_format)
Write-Host
Write-Host "-----------------------------"
Write-Host
Write-Host "This example is for the am pm clock with hh"
Write-Host "Again, ToUniversalTime() must be used when using [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]"
Write-Host
$my_date_ampm_time   = "20190720110000.000000+000"
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($my_date_ampm_time).ToUniversalTime();
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($my_date_ampm_time).ToUniversalTime().ToSTring($date_format)
[datetime]::ParseExact($my_date_ampm_time,"yyyyMMddhhmmss.000000+000",$null).ToSTring($date_format)
```

### Output

```
This example is for the 24hr clock with HH
ToUniversalTime() must be used when using [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]

20 July 2019 17:00:00
2019-07-20 17:00
2019-07-20 17:00

-----------------------------

This example is for the am pm clock with hh
Again, ToUniversalTime() must be used when using [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]

20 July 2019 11:00:00
2019-07-20 11:00
2019-07-20 11:00
```

---

MS doc on `[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: This answer help me, at last! So we can check which one is correct and working. I was looking for the correct way to format the date from `Get-WmiObject win32_process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessId -eq "2036"}` and format the "CreationDate"

Answer (score 2):

```
$invoice = "Jul-16"
[datetime]$newInvoice = "01-" + $invoice

$newInvoice.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

There you go, use a type accelerator, but also into a new var, if you want to use it elsewhere, use it like so: `$newInvoice.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`as `$newInvoice` will always be in the datetime format, unless you cast it as a string afterwards, but will lose the ability to perform datetime functions - adding days etc...

Answer (score 1):

Hope below helps!

```
PS C:\Users\aameer>$invoice = $object.'Invoice Month'
$invoice = "01-" + $invoice
[datetime]$Format_date =$invoice
```

Now type is converted. You can use method or can access any property.

```
Example :$Format_date.AddDays(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy; in my case it works with;

Input:

```
$Date = '29-07-2022'
```

DateFormat Convertion:

```
[datetime]::parseexact($date, 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null).ToString('dd-MMMM-yyyy')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a different but related need to convert a number (seconds) into days/hours/seconds etc.

```
$seconds = 41414141
New-Timespan -seconds $seconds
```

[image]