# PowerShell command output convert to date and time

Tags: powershell, parsing, output, powershell-cmdlet

How would one convert a PowerShell command output that retrieves some date/time like to a readable date/time string?
The command is

```
((Get-ComputerRestorePoint)[-1]).CreationTime
```

Which basically retrieves the last restore point created date and time, but in a weird format like 20190109100614.556883-000

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717490/powershell-convert-string-to-datetime

Comment: that cmdlet appears to be a _really_ simple wrapper around a WMI call. so you can use the usual fix for those datetime strings ... `.ConvertToDateTime()`.

Comment: tried that on my multiple trial and error. no go. ((Get-ComputerRestorePoint)[-1]).CreationTime.ConvertToDateTime()
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ConvertToDateTime'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion can be done via RestorePoint object. Like so,

```
$rp=((Get-ComputerRestorePoint)[-1])
$rp.ConvertToDateTime($rp.CreationTime).ToString("u")

# Result
2019-01-08 08:24:24Z
```

The `u` format is [universal sortable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-universal-sortable-u-format-specifier) sepcifier, there are quite a few alternatives too.

Answer (score 2):

the reason your previous try failed is that you went at it *logically* instead of doing it the WMI timestamp way. [*grin*] this works ...

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$RPCreationTime = (Get-ComputerRestorePoint)[-1]
$RPCreationTime = $RPCreationTime.ConvertToDateTime($RPCreationTime.CreationTime)

# the Out-Host is needed to avoid the display system trying to combine the two items
$RPCreationTime.GetType() | Out-Host
$RPCreationTime
```

output ...

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType


2019 January 09, Wednesday 3:00:13 AM
```