# Convert text based date to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: string, powershell, date

I have a csv file with date data stored in string format e.g. 'Sat 9th Feb 2019'.  Using Powershell, how would I convert that to a date format of dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: It is always helpful to post code that you have tried even if the question does seem simple to you. Sometimes code examples and the question don't align. We all approach problems differently, so the more information we have the better we can tackle problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the previously answered question does everything Andy needs here. When you run a `(get-date).getdatetimeformats()` command, nothing matches his starting input format. The following should output what you want:

```
"Sat 9th Feb 2019" -replace "(\d+)(th|nd|st|rd)",'$1' | get-date -format "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

The replace here is using a regex replace, and it is case-insensitive `(\d+)` looks for one or more digits and calls them group 1. `(th|nd|st|rd)` looks for strings of th, nd, st, or rd and calls them group 2. Since those groups are next to each other, the regex expects one or more digits followed directly by one of the four strings. `$1` is a way to only show the contents of capture group 1. If we take `24th` as an example, `24` qualifies as one or more digits and is named group 1. `th` qualifies as one of the four strings and is named group 2. The replace operator is replacing group 1 and group 2 with just group 1. Therefore, 24th becomes 24.

Here is a practical example of your scenario:

```
$CSVData = import-csv X:\Temp\MyCSVFile.csv
PS H:\> $CSVData

Date              Data
----              ----
Sat 9th Feb 2019  Data about something
Thu 31st Jan 2019 January data
Sat 2nd Feb 2019  Groundhog Day
Sun 3rd Mar 2019  Beginning of March

PS H:\> $CSVData.date -replace "(\d+)(th|nd|st|rd)",'$1' | get-date -format "dd/MM/yyyy"
09/02/2019
31/01/2019
02/02/2019
03/03/2019
```

If you want to reformat the date along with output the rest of the CSV file data, then you can run:

```
PS H:\> $CSVData | select-object @{n='Date';e={$_.date -replace "(\d+)(th|nd|st|rd)",'$1' | get-date -format "dd/MM/yyyy"}},Data

Date       Data
----       ----
09/02/2019 Data about something
31/01/2019 January data
02/02/2019 Groundhog Day
03/03/2019 Beginning of March
```

If your intention is to update the file with the newly formatted data, then you can run the following to put the updates in a file called NewCSVFile.csv:

```
$CSVData | select-object @{n='Date';e={$_.date -replace "(\d+)(th|nd|st|rd)",'$1' | get-date -format "dd/MM/yyyy"}},Data | export-csv C:\Temp\NewCSVFile.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thank you to all who answered this post.  I didn't supply any code as I was completely clueless as to how to go about solving this issue without making a messy hack using find\replace and substrings etc.  I'll be filing this one away for future use.

Answer (score 1):

$invoice = '01-Jul-16'
[datetime]::parseexact($invoice, 'dd-MMM-yy', $null)

Question already answered at
[Powershell convert string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717490/powershell-convert-string-to-datetime)

Placeholders for different formats can be obtained from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: While the links are helpful in general (though the 2nd one should be to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings instead), I don't think there's a format string to pass to `.ParseExact()` that can handle the _ordinal suffixes_ present in the OP's input (e.g., `th`), given that it would have to recognize _multiple_ potential suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

i could not find a way to escape the `th` in `9th` [or any other suffixed number]. so this ...

- breaks the string at the spaces
- removes any non-digits in the 2nd array item
- rejoins the parts into a string with space delimiters
- uses the normal `Get-Date -Date` to convert to a `[datetime]` object

here's the code ...

```
$DateString = 'Sat 9th Feb 2019'

$SplitDateString = $DateString.Split(' ')
$SplitDateString[1] = $SplitDateString[1] -replace '[^0-9]', ''
$CleanedDateString = $SplitDateString -join ' '

Get-Date -Date $CleanedDateString
```

output ...

```
2019 February 09, Saturday 12:00:00 AM
```

my locale has been overridden to use yyyy MMMM dd as the long date format [and yyyy MM dd as the short date format].

---

here's a version that directly removes the ordinal suffixes [thanks to mklement0 for the phrase that let me finally ID those] ...

```
$OrdinalSuffixList = @(
    'st'
    'nd'
    'rd'
    'th'
    )
$RegexOrdinalSuffixList = $OrdinalSuffixList -join '|'

$DateString = 'Sat 9th Feb 2019'

Get-Date -Date ($DateString -replace "(\d+)$RegexOrdinalSuffixList", '$1')
```

output ...

```
2019 February 09, Saturday 12:00:00 AM
```

the regex above finds the "ordinal suffixes" and replaces them with nothing. at that point the normal `Get-Date` can parse that date-string layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your **input date strings have ordinal suffixes** ((1)`st`, (2)`nd`, (3)`rd`, n-`th`), the simplest way to **convert them to `[datetime]` instances is to simply *remove* these suffixes before *casting* to `[datetime]`**; the **result can then easily be *reformatted*** as needed:

```
PS> ([datetime] ('Sat 9th Feb 2019' -replace '(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)')).ToString('dd"/"MM"/"yyyy')
09/02/2019
```

`-replace '(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)'` uses a regex to replace suffixes `st` or (`|`)  `nd` or `rd` or `th` after a digit (`\d`, via a look-behind assertion, `(?<=...)`) with the (implied) *empty string*, thereby effectively *removing all ordinal suffixes*.

Note:

- Using a `[datetime]` *cast* interprets its operand as a date string formatted according to the rules of the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) (which is based on US English) - irrespective of the session's *current* culture (as reflected in `Get-Culture`).
- It is `MM`, not `mm` that represents the two-digit 1-based month index (e.g., `02` for February).
- Use of an *unquoted* `/` in a format string passed to `.ToString()` wouldn't be a *literal* `/`: instead, it represents the culture-appropriate date-component separator, which in English language-based cultures happens to be `/`, but may be a different character in other cultures; *quoting* `/` - by enclosing it in `"` (as above) or `'` - ensures its literal use - see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals).
- The assumption is that the input dates are *internally consistent*, that is, the weekday (e.g., `Sat`) must match the actual calendar day implied by the rest of the string - if not, you'll get an error.

---

A slower, but more PowerShell-idiomatic alternative is to adapt [AdminOfThings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings):

```
PS> Get-Date ('Sat 9th Feb 2019' -replace '(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)') -Format 'dd"/"MM"/"yyyy'
09/02/2019
```

Note:

- Due to a [longstanding bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3348) that won't be fixed, arguments passed to *cmdlet* parameters (such as `Get-Date`'s (implied) `-Date` parameter) are actually converted from strings based on the *current* culture, not the *invariant* culture.
- However, in the specific case of type `[datetime]`, *English* month names (e.g., `Feb` or `February`) are *always* recognized, *in addition to* the culture-specific names.