# Error in turning imported CSV column into all datetime in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an imported CSV file with 5 columns of numbers, and one column of datetime.

As they all came out as strings, I have successfully converted the numbers to integers, but seem to be getting an error with converting the dates to datetime...

I have been helped by the article [Convert a string to datetime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717490/convert-a-string-to-datetime-in-Powershell), but even though I am absolutely positive that I am not making a mistake in the parsing of the date it is not working and I get the same error message that the user in that article referenced was experiencing.

Is it because I am not going about changing the data type for all the column in the correct way?

```
$import = Import-Csv C:\path\csv.csv

$time = $import | select Time #time is the name of column

[DateTime]::ParseExact($time, "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", $null)
```

But my output is still...

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method 
named 'ParseExact'.
At line:6 char:1
+ [int32]::ParseExact($time, "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", $null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Am I going about converting the whole column in the correct way?

Comment: Without knowing your source data it's hard to diagnose anything like this, but will the PS commandlet not work?   get-date $time -Format 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt'

Comment: at the point you try to parse the $Time item is is NOT a string ... it's an array of objects with one property named `Time` that contains the date string. you will need to iterate thru the array and refer to the value thru the prop name - something like `$Time.Time`.

Comment: Don't run `[int32]:ParseExact()` when you intend to run `[DateTime]::ParseExact()`? Also, you want to `Select-Object -Expand` the field "time" and parse each value individually.

Answer (score 0):

**As @Scepticalist posted, without the source data this is a little harder**

When you are importing the CSV now, the property for the time column is most likely being defined as a string.

You can check that with this:

```
$import | get-member *
```

With that in mind and using this simple CSV as an example:

```
Time,Num1,Num2,Num3  
11/15/2019,1234,2345,3456
11/16/2019,2345,3456,4567
11/17/2019,3456,4567,5678
```

I can cast the "Time" column as DateTime at the same time I am importing the CSV:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\CSV.csv |
Foreach-Object {
   $_.Time = $_.Time -as [datetime]
   $_
}
```

Now, when I check the properties of the $csv variable:

```
$csv | get-member *
```

Now the "Definition" for the "Time" column will be in the correct "DateTime" format.