# Extract dates from filenames then process files by date in ascending order - Powershell

Tags: powershell

First of all I'll supply my code and then explain.

```
$toImport = gci "\\server\folder\*" -include "Examplefile*.txt"
$toImport = $toImport.fullname

$date_of_file = @()

foreach($item in $toImport){
    $date_of_file += (split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6) 

}

write-host ($date_of_file | sort-object)
```

I am getting filenames with get-childitem, then just putting their full path into an array. My `$toImport` variable holds the filepaths and it looks like:

```
\\server\folder\Examplefile010220.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile010320.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile010420.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile010520.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile120919.txt
```

I then use `split-path` on it to get just the filename where I can run `.substring()` on it to extract the dates and then I add those dates into variable `$date_of_file`, which using the above example will hold these values... `010220 010320 010420 010520 120919`

I tried to then sort these dates in ascending order because I have a later part of my script that will process the files but they must be done in order.

Some things I've tried to fix the above posted script: 
    (get-date -date $date_of_file | sort-object)

```
($date_of_file.ToString('MMddyy') | sort-object)

$date_of_file += ((split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6) ).toString("MMddyy")

$date_of_file += get-date -date ((split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6) )

($date_of_file | Sort-Object { $_. -as [datetime] })

$date_of_file += [datetime]::parseexact(((split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6) ), 'MMddyy', $null).ToString('MMddyy')
```

How can I get this to sort by date in ascending order? So far every time I try something I'm running into errors or this date is still at the end of the list, '120919', when it should be first.

================= **UPDATE**

```
$toImport = gci "\\server\folder\*" -include "Examplefile*.txt"
$toImport = $toImport.fullname
cls

$date_of_file = @()

foreach($item in $toImport){
    $date_of_file += [datetime]::parseexact(((split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6) ), 'MMddyy', $null)

}

write-host ($date_of_file | Sort-Object)
```

This bit seems to work but it's putting the format of the dates into a format that looks like `Thursday, January 2, 2020 12:00:00 AM`. and I tried to do .ToString('MMddyy') on the result but I'm getting this error `Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".`

Comment: Try [this stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717490/convert-a-string-to-datetime-in-powershell)

Comment: That doesn't work. You can see I tried that above. After doing the parseexact function on the dates, I do get the dates... but sorting it isn't working as expected with `($date_of_file | Sort-Object)` This is the foundation of my problem.

Comment: this is the order it's sorting and it's driving me crazy: `010220
010320
010420
010520
120919`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concise and efficient solution that directly sorts the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem` in the chronological order implied by the `MMddyy`-formatted date strings embedded in the file names:

```
Get-ChildItem \\server\folder -Filter Examplefile*.txt |
  Sort-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '.+(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$3$1$2' }
```

- `Get-ChildItem \\server\folder -Filter Examplefile*.txt`:

  - `-Filter` is the most efficient way to find files matching a given wildcard pattern, because it filters at the source (the filesystem) rather than retrieving all items first and then making PowerShell filter after the fact (which is what happens with `-Include`).
- `Sort-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '.+(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$3$1$2' }`:

  - Passing a script block (`{ ... }`) to `Sort-Object`'s (implied) `-Property` parameter causes the script block to be evaluated for each input object, with the input object at hand reflected in automatic variable `$_`.
  - The [`-replace` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) uses a regex-based string substitution that effectively rearranges the embedded date string from `MMddyy` into `yyMMdd` format and sorts based on the latter, so that *lexical* sorting equals *chronological* sorting.

Comment: Thank you, I have ditched my .substring() in favor of doing it this way.  Seems a lot more flexible. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer seems like a great solution.  Here is my updated answer giving you a sorted array of `[pscustomobjects]` with the filenames included that you can then reference back to your filenames with `$date_of_file.fileNM`

```
$toImport = gci "server\folder\*"
$toImport = $toImport.fullname

$date_of_file = @()

foreach($item in $toImport){
    $date_of_file += [pscustomobject]@{
                      "fileNM" = $item;
                      "dispDate" = (split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6);
                      "dateStamp"=  [datetime]::parseexact((split-path $item -leaf).substring(11,6),'MMddyy', $null)
                      }
    }

$date_of_file = $date_of_file | Sort-Object -Property dateStamp

$date_of_file.dispDate
```

----------- Old answer below -----------

This works for me:

```
$date_of_file = @()


$date_of_file +=  [datetime]::parseexact("010220", 'MMddyy', $null)
$date_of_file +=  [datetime]::parseexact("010320", 'MMddyy', $null)
$date_of_file +=  [datetime]::parseexact("010420", 'MMddyy', $null)
$date_of_file +=  [datetime]::parseexact("010520", 'MMddyy', $null)
$date_of_file +=  [datetime]::parseexact("120919", 'MMddyy', $null)


$date_of_file | Sort-Object {$_ -as [datetime]}
```

Comment: Looks straightforward but doing that does not format it as MMddyy. It's formatted like `Monday, December 9, 2019 12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 1):

i think you may have a problem in what you are SEEING. your sorted list *should* have the `120919` file at the END of the "newest first" listing since the others are all in 2020, not 2019.

however, here is my version of a solution to the problem. the "magic" in this case is getting only the numbers from the end of the `.BaseName` of the file. since you threw that away, i had to use a split and a regex. [*grin*]

```
$FileNameList = @(
    '\\server\folder\Examplefile010220.txt'
    '\\server\folder\Examplefile010320.txt'
    '\\server\folder\Examplefile010420.txt'
    '\\server\folder\Examplefile010520.txt'
    '\\server\folder\Examplefile120919.txt'
    )

$FileNameList |
    # this would be far easier if you have left things as fileinfo objects [*grin*] 
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property {
        [datetime]::ParseExact(($_.Split('.')[0] -replace '.+(\d{6})', '$1'), 'MMddyy', $Null)
        }
```

output ...

```
\\server\folder\Examplefile010520.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile010420.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile010320.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile010220.txt
\\server\folder\Examplefile120919.txt
```

note that the last file is from 2019 and the others are all from 2020. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.  It adds a `SortableName` property which is yyddMM, then sorting by that property:

```
dir "\\server\folder\*" -include "Examplefile*.txt" | `
  Select-Object -Property *, @{ Name = 'SortableName'; Expression = {$_.BaseName.Substring(15) + $_.BaseName.Substring(11,4) }} | `
  Sort-Object -Property SortableName | Select-Object -Property FullName
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to create an intermediate calculated property just in order to sort by it; you can pass your script block (`{$_.BaseName....}`) _directly_ to `Sort-Object -Property`.