# How to Convert datetime formats using powershell

Tags: powershell, date, datetime

I Have a variable stored with this value

```
PS C:\Users\> $Time

Monday, November 30, 2020 8:55:01 AM
Sunday, October 18, 2020 11:10:01 PM
Sunday, November 8, 2020 10:40:34 PM
Sunday, November 8, 2020 11:47:37 PM
Sunday, November 8, 2020 10:59:57 PM
Tuesday, December 1, 2020 3:15:42 AM
Monday, November 30, 2020 7:00:32 PM
Monday, November 30, 2020 12:19:06 AM
Monday, November 30, 2020 7:01:34 PM
Tuesday, December 1, 2020 1:12:10 AM
Tuesday, December 1, 2020 2:37:18 AM
Sunday, November 1, 2020 7:39:34 PM
Sunday, September 27, 2020 11:48:38 PM
```

I want the time formats of the variable $**time** to change to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" so that ALL of the list is displayed

```
PS C:\Users\> $Time

2020-11-30 08:55:01
2020-10-18 11:10:01
2020-11-08 10:40:34
2020-11-08 11:47:37
2020-11-08 10:59:57
2020-12-01 03:15:42
2020-11-30 07:00:32
2020-11-30 12:19:06
2020-11-30 07:01:34
2020-12-01 01:12:10
2020-12-01 02:37:18
2020-11-01 07:39:34
2020-09-27 11:48:38
```

Please help me creating a code for the same

thanks

Comment: related: [Convert a string to datetime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38717490/10197418)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty common question that gets asked here on StackOverflow, however, it seems most of the answers are directed towards converting a variable which stores a single date, to a formatted string.

Whereas you have an array of dates you want to convert.

I'm going to make the assumption that you have an `Array` of `DateTime` values, and not an `Array` of `String`.

For starters, there's TONS of blogs and articles about this, not to mention the documentation.

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/formatting-date-strings-with-powershell/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date

Depending on how you need to use this data there is a million different ways to do this.

Primarily, you need to learn how to perform actions against an array of objects. Using things like `ForEach`, `ForEach-Object`, `Select-Object`, etc. Once you learn how to use those, then the problem just becomes "how do you format a date to a string", which is all over the place on here and the rest of the internet.

Here's some examples:

```
# Use this to generate sample data:
$Time = 10000,9000,8000,7000,6000,5000,4000,3000,2000,1000 |
    ForEach-Object { (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$_) }

## Various solutions:
$Time | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') }

$Time | ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }
$Time | ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }
$Time | ForEach-Object { Get-Date $_ -f 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }

$Time | Select-Object @{N='TimeString'; E={$_.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}}

foreach ($tv in $time) { $tv.ToSTring('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') }

$Time.ForEach({$_.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')})

# Other methods submitted in comments, thanks @iRon
$Time | ForEach-Object ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
$Time.ForEach('ToString', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Note that this is case sensitive.

- `MM` - Means the two digit month value
- `mm` - Means the two digit day value

Comment: FYI, I have created an issue proposal for [a Format alias for the ToString method to all scalar objects](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14372)

Comment: You might simplify the first example to: `$Time |ForEach-Object ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')` or: `$Time |% ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: Or: `$Time.ForEach('ToString', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')` (credits to [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0))