# Convert a Text File to JSON using PowerShell

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I am working in AWS S3 storage where we have buckets and files are being added to the buckets. The Bucket information is logged into another bucket in text format.

I would like to convert the log information stored in text files to JSON. there however is no Key-Pair Information in the file.

**The contents of the LogFile is as below: -**

`fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341 s3Samplebucket [10/Mar/2021:03:27:29 +0000] 171.60.235.108 fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341 MX1XP335Q5YFS06H REST.HEAD.BUCKET - "HEAD /s3Samplebucket HTTP/1.1" 200 - - - 13 13 "-" "S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.964 Linux/4.9.230-0.1.ac.224.84.332.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.282-b08 java/1.8.0_282 vendor/Oracle_Corporation" - AMNo4/b/T+5JdEVQpLkqz0SV8VDXyd3odEFmK+5LvanuzgIXW2Lv87OBl5r5tbSZ/yjW5zfFQsA= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2`

The individual values for the Log file are as below: - 
**Log fields**

**Bucket Owner:** fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341

**Bucket:** S3SampleBucket

**Time:** [11/Mar/2021:** 06:** 52:** 33 +0000]

**Remote IP:** 183.87.60.172

**Requester:** arn:** aws:** iam:** :** 486031527132:** user/jdoe

**Request ID:** 9YQ1MWABKNRPX3MP

**Operation:** REST.GET.LOCATION

**Key:** - (BLANK)

**Request-URI:** "GET /?location HTTP/1.1"

**HTTP status:** 200

**Error Code:** - (BLANK)

**Bytes Sent:** 137

**Object Size:** - (BLANK)

**Total Time:** 17

**Turn-Around Time:** - (BLANK)

**Referer:** "-"  (BLANK)

**User-Agen:** "AWSPowerShell/4.1.9.0 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_10.0.18363.0 WindowsPowerShell/5.0 ClientSync"

**Version Id:** - (BLANK)

**Host Id:** Q5WBxJNrwsspFmtOG+d2YN0xAtvbq1sdqm9vh6AflXdMCmny5VC3bZmyTBZavKGpO3J/uz+IfK0=

**Signature Version:** SigV4

**Cipher Suite:** ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256

**Authentication Type:** AuthHeader

**Host Header:** S3SampleBucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

**TLS version:** TLSv1.2

I can add the Value in a Configuration file is what I can think of. I would like to do this in either PowerShell or Python.

Any assistance wold be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log format can be interpreted as a CSV (with a whitespace delimiter), so you could parse it using `Import-Csv`/`ConvertFrom-Csv`:

```
$columns = 'Bucket Owner', 'Bucket', 'Time', 'Remote IP', 'Requester', 'Request ID', 'Operation', 'Key', 'Request-URI', 'HTTP status', 'Error Code', 'Bytes Sent', 'Object Size', 'Total Time', 'Turn-Around Time', 'Referer', 'User-Agen', 'Version Id', 'Host Id', 'Signature Version', 'Cipher Suite', 'Authentication Type', 'Host Header', 'TLS version'

$data = @'
fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341 s3Samplebucket [10/Mar/2021:03:27:29 +0000] 171.60.235.108 fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341 MX1XP335Q5YFS06H REST.HEAD.BUCKET - "HEAD /s3Samplebucket HTTP/1.1" 200 - - - 13 13 "-" "S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.964 Linux/4.9.230-0.1.ac.224.84.332.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.282-b08 java/1.8.0_282 vendor/Oracle_Corporation" - AMNo4/b/T+5JdEVQpLkqz0SV8VDXyd3odEFmK+5LvanuzgIXW2Lv87OBl5r5tbSZ/yjW5zfFQsA= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2
'@

$parsedLog = $data |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header $columns
```

Now the resulting object is easily converted to JSON:

```
PS ~> $parsedLog |ConvertTo-Json
{
    "Bucket Owner":  "fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341",
    "Bucket":  "s3Samplebucket",
    "Time":  "[10/Mar/2021:03:27:29",
    "Remote IP":  "+0000]",
    "Requester":  "171.60.235.108",
    "Request ID":  "fd89d80d676948bd913040b667965ef6a50a9c80a12f38c504f497953aedc341",
    "Operation":  "MX1XP335Q5YFS06H",
    "Key":  "REST.HEAD.BUCKET",
    "Request-URI":  "-",
    "HTTP status":  "HEAD /s3Samplebucket HTTP/1.1",
    "Error Code":  "200",
    "Bytes Sent":  "-",
    "Object Size":  "-",
    "Total Time":  "-",
    "Turn-Around Time":  "13",
    "Referer":  "13",
    "User-Agen":  "-",
    "Version Id":  "S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.964 Linux/4.9.230-0.1.ac.224.84.332.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.282-b08 java/1.8.0_282 vendor/Oracle_Corporation",
    "Host Id":  "-",
    "Signature Version":  "AMNo4/b/T+5JdEVQpLkqz0SV8VDXyd3odEFmK+5LvanuzgIXW2Lv87OBl5r5tbSZ/yjW5zfFQsA=",
    "Cipher Suite":  "SigV4",
    "Authentication Type":  "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
    "Host Header":  "AuthHeader",
    "TLS version":  "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
}
```

---

In your case, to read the file from disk, simply replace `$data = ...` and `$data |ConvertFrom-Csv` statements with `Import-Csv`:

```
$parsedLog = Import-Csv -Path .\path\to\s3requests.log -Delimiter ' ' -Header $columns
```

Comment: we cant use space " " as there are space between the data which essentially is part of the same set... 

**For Example**
`[10/Mar/2021:03:27:29 +0000] 171.60.235.108 `

should be

"Time":  "[10/Mar/2021:03:27:29 +0000],<BR>
"Remote IP":  "171.60.235.108",<BR>

**as per your code it is **

"Time":  "[10/Mar/2021:03:27:29",
"Remote IP":  "+0000]",
"Requester":  "171.60.235.108",

Comment: @NottyHead Oh, I see. `(Get-Content file.log) -replace '\[([^\]]+)\]','"$1"' |ConvertFrom-Csv ...` should do the trick

Comment: Another help requested @user:712649
In the above Example, how do I convert the time stored in [10/Mar/2021:03:27:29 +0000] to MM-dd-yyyyTHH:mm:ssZ format. The reason I ask is we need this data to be used in a downstream system where the data is stored as 03-10-2021T03:27:29Z

Comment: @NottyHead There are 100s of existing posts on this site already answering that question. [Try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717490/convert-a-string-to-datetime-in-powershell)

Comment: @712649
$parsedLog = $data -replace '\[([^\]]+)\]','"$1"' |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header $columns $date_format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" 
$parsedLog | Select ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Time',"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss +0000",$null).ToSTring($date_format)) 
**Error: - **
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." At line:18 char:1 + $parsedLog | Select ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Time',"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH ... + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: @NottyHead Please stop pasting code in comments. If you have a question about how to use `[Datetime]::ParseExact()` in a pipeline, use the search functionality and/or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks for the help so far